# Change size of bitmap in splash screen layer-list

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

Here's my splash screen:

**splash_screen.xml**

```
<item android:drawable="@color/colorBackground"/>

<item android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp" android:gravity="center">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/truthordare_splash"
        android:gravity="center"  />
</item>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/play</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
</style>
```

The bitmap image takes up nearly the whole screen. I want to reduce its size, but changing the `width` and `height` of the parent `<item>` does nothing. Why is this?

PS: the `truthordare_splash` is a dynamic image based on the screen density:
[image]

How can I change the size of the bitmap?